# React accessing self props without extending class / function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I am building a custom component in React Native that will automatically manage the components passed as children.

This component will also add custom props to the children.

One caveat however is that children components are unable to use these props directly; instead, creating a SFC or extending React.Component is necessary in order to access the `props` object of those childs.

I was wondering if there is a way to access those added props without doing that?

In the code below, for example, I'd like to be able to access the `managerProp` like this:

```
<ManagerComponent>
  <Child onPress={ managerProp.handleOnPress }>
    {managerProp.something}
  </Child>
</ManagerComponent>
```

Comment: How are you adding props to children?

Comment: I am using `React.cloneElement(child, { additionalProps={ ... }})`. This is called in the renderItem callback of React Native's FlatList component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to have your `ManagerComponent` expose a render prop (basically a function it will call to render its children).  It can pass in its "extra" props to this function.  You can use children as the render prop which leads to something like:

```
function ManagerComponent({children}) {
   const extraProps = {handleOnPress: ..., ...}
   // The trick is we call children as a function instead
   // of treating it as a component to render
   return <div>{children(extraProps)}</div>
}

ManagerComponent.propTypes = { children: PropTypes.func.isRequired }

function Foo() {
  return (
     <ManagerComponent>
        {managerProps => (
          <Child onPress={managerProps.handleOnPress}>
             {managerProps.something}
          </Child>)
        }
     </ManagerComponent>
  )
}
```

Here is a [blog article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-render-props) (not mine) that discusses this concept in more detail.

Comment: The method used in the article, looks like it is just as same as having that `{ managerProps => { ... } }` arrow function as a normal SFC function, but without the hassle of actually writing that function somewhere else in the code. 
  Did I understand correctly ?

Comment: sort of.  The render function (the lambda) has the context of the containing component and can use its state and variables.